# salesforce integration with facebook/twitter/linkedIN

Tags: facebook

I want to achieve a functionality where if i create a facebook page of my application, and someone likes it, they should automatically be converted into leads.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this. And while I've never done it, I remember watching a demo where HP used site.com to build a microsite for that.

Additionally, using the Web2lead functionality and the javascript sdk for salesforce you could probably build it into your face book app. Generate your web2lead form in salesforce, and then use the action / method / field names (make sure to send the hidden fields as well) from an ajax call in your facebook app. (I think you can do that)

Comment: I still don't get it.. could you be a bit more elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I've never directly done it. but I do know it's possible esp through site.com micro sites. Perhaps the site.com workbook ( http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.salesforce.com%2Fus%2Fdeveloper%2Fdocs%2Fworkbook_siteforce%2Fwb_siteforce.pdf&ei=AexvUse5Fa-E2gXup4DgAg&usg=AFQjCNGEflyY7KByS79_Rr0stXno_R13CA&bvm=bv.55123115,d.b2I ) can help

Answer (score 0):

Sam,

Were you able to accomplish the task of lead capture in salesforce when a person likes your facebook page? could you provide me some insights about this?

Iam in the same situation to capture the leads!

P.s: I have tried the above tip but the process sounds very cumbersome.

Comment: yes i was able to do it.. but you have to make a site from site.com. I then made an app on facebook. The site's visualforce page was able to capture the leads details which were then stored as a lead.